# Bypass the certificate warning pages in Chrome for a specific URL

Tags: networking, google-chrome, certificate, security-warning

I manage an Aruba access point virtual controller cluster and when I visit the local management URL by IP (no DNS involved) over the local network using Chrome I get these two warning pages that I have to click through to get to the site:

[image: first]

[image: second]

The Aruba AP cluster is not accessible from outside the network, and is also on a VLAN that is segregated from the rest of the network using Layer 3 firewall rules, so I'm not concerned about a man-in-the-middle attack scenario.

Is there a way to whitelist this specific host to not display those warning pages?

Also, just to mention: if I use `http://` instead of `https://` it still changes the address to `https://` immediately and brings me to the same page.

Comment: You need to add the certificate into the OS user's certificate store. Of course this won't solve the fact the certificate is using an insecure cipher